# Neperian Logarithm on ActionScript 2?

Tags: flash, math, actionscript

How do i calculate the neperian logarithm on AS2 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Naperian or natural logarithm, i.e. log base E  it is just [Math.log](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary457.html)